# How can I use SQL to simulate a query using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for previous days?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

EDIT: My question was closed for being a duplicate. However, it is definitely not a duplicate, the questions it references as duplicates are completely different. Using the method in the duplicate answers, I would need to rerun the same query 180 times. This question should have been left open.

SOLUTION: For anyone that does happen to stumble upon this question, here is what I did to fix it (questions marked as duplicates are not correct, they just suggest subtracting -1 day):

1. Used @AdrianKlaver idea to create a calendar table and CROSS JOIN LATERAL to my original table
2. Used a query to calculate the age based on the calendar table
3. Used a Window function max(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY job, report_date)

I think this should be a basic question, but getting stuck. I think a Window function, maybe using "lead" or "lag" should be able to handle what I want, but not sure about the actual logic I need. Also, this could be done programmatically with a loop, but I would rather use a pure SQL approach.

Database is Postgres 15. Here is the history table.

```bash
+----+-----------------------------+-----------+
| id |        timestamp            |    job    |
+----+-----------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Upload   |
|  2 | 2023-02-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Pipeline |
|  3 | 2023-03-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Upload   |
|  4 | 2023-04-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Rebuild  |
|  5 | 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Pipeline |
|  6 | 2023-06-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Rebuild  |
|  7 | 2023-07-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Rebuild  |
|  8 | 2023-08-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Pipeline |
|  9 | 2023-09-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Upload   |
| 10 | 2023-10-01T00:00:00.000000Z |  Rebuild  |
+----+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

Simple query will retrieve the age of the jobs based on the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. The idea is, if a job is over a certain age, it will send out a status email, like "overdue".

```sql
SELECT job,
       timestamp,
       (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamptz - timestamp::timestamptz) AS age
FROM history;
```

```bash
   job    |          timestamp          |           age
----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------
 Upload   | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z | 157 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z | 156 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000000Z | 155 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000000Z | 154 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 153 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 152 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-01-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 151 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z | 150 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000Z | 149 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-01-10T00:00:00.000000Z | 148 days 21:22:34.481041
(10 rows)
```

Now, how would I run this same query using yesterday as the date, then 2 days ago, then 3 days ago, etc., all the way through the beginning of the year? (Or some other historical time). The results would be ouptut into one result set.

Output would like similar to this:

```sql
   job    |      report_timestamp       |      timestamp              |        age
----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------
 Upload   | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z | 155 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z | 154 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000000Z | 153 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000000Z | 152 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 151 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 150 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 149 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z | 148 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000Z | 147 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-10T00:00:00.000000Z | 146 days 21:22:34.481041

 Upload   | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z | 156 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z | 155 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000000Z | 154 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000000Z | 153 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 152 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 151 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 150 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z | 149 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000Z | 148 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-10T00:00:00.000000Z | 147 days 21:22:34.481041

 Upload   | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z | 157 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z | 156 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000000Z | 155 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000000Z | 154 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 153 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z | 152 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 151 days 21:22:34.481041
 Pipeline | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z | 150 days 21:22:34.481041
 Upload   | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000Z | 149 days 21:22:34.481041
 Rebuild  | 2023-06-07T00:00:00.000000Z | 2023-01-10T00:00:00.000000Z | 148 days 21:22:34.481041
(30 rows)
```

Is it even possible using pure SQL? Or should I visit a stored procedure or push that logic into python?

It's as if I need some sort of snapshot and time travel function to run the query as it appeared on each day.

Thanks for any help and let me know if there's information I left out that is helpful.

Have looked at various Window functions, DATEDIFF, and date calculation logic, but coming up with blanks.

Thanks to Adrian Klaver, I think this is close:

```sql
WITH history_report AS
(
SELECT *
FROM history
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
generate_series('2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z'::timestamp,
'2023-06-01T00:00:00.000000Z'::timestamp,
'24 hours')
)

SELECT id,
       timestamp,
       job,
       generate_series,
       (generate_series::timestamptz - timestamp::timestamptz) AS age
FROM history_report;
```

```bash
 id |          timestamp          |   job    |   generate_series   |        age
----+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+-------------------

 1  | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z | Upload   | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 150 days 07:00:00
 2  | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z | Pipeline | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 149 days 07:00:00
 3  | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000000Z | Upload   | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 148 days 07:00:00
 4  | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 147 days 07:00:00
 5  | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | Pipeline | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 146 days 07:00:00
 6  | 2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 145 days 07:00:00
 7  | 2023-01-07T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 144 days 07:00:00
 8  | 2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z | Pipeline | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 143 days 07:00:00
 9  | 2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000Z | Upload   | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 142 days 07:00:00
 10 | 2023-01-10T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 141 days 07:00:00
 1  | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z | Upload   | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 151 days 07:00:00
 2  | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z | Pipeline | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 150 days 07:00:00
 3  | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000000Z | Upload   | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 149 days 07:00:00
 4  | 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 148 days 07:00:00
 5  | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | Pipeline | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 147 days 07:00:00
 6  | 2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 146 days 07:00:00
 7  | 2023-01-07T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 145 days 07:00:00
 8  | 2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z | Pipeline | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 144 days 07:00:00
 9  | 2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000Z | Upload   | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 143 days 07:00:00
 10 | 2023-01-10T00:00:00.000000Z | Rebuild  | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 142 days 07:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you @fubar, it's close. I edited my answer to provide the sample output I'm looking to do. The query would ideally roll back each day and then present the snapshot for each day in the output.

Comment: Join to `select * from  generate_series('2023-01-01'::timestamp, '2023-06-07'::timestamp, '1day') as t(report_timestamp);`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that's awesome, I think I am close. Thank you, will post some updated code.